# KNN (<->) order by -- possible to use spatial index with a secondary order by?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, distance, spatial-join, knn

From reading here as well as the docs, I know how to use the <-> operator in my order by in order to do KNN search, and this is fast and uses the gist spatial index as expected. However, I have a use case that requires a secondary order by --

Something like:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)
SELECT
    addresses.name,
    addresses.address_line_one,
    addresses.city,
    addresses.state,
    addresses.zip_code,
    addresses.row_id,
    customers.first_name,
    customers.last_name,
    customers.characteristics,
    customer_id,
    customers_at_locations.address_id,
    customers_at_locations.id,
    (customers_at_locations.latlong <-> ST_Point(-118.38154, 34.09401)::geography) / 1609.34 AS distance
FROM
    customers_at_locations
JOIN
    addresses ON addresses.row_id = customers_at_locations.address_id AND addresses.updated_at = '2023-12-08 19:29:42.091863'
JOIN
    customers ON customers.assoc_id= customers_at_locations.customer_id
WHERE
  ((customers_at_locations.latlong <-> ST_Point(-118.38154, 34.09401)::geography) / 1609.34) < 50
    AND customers_at_locations.location_type = 'home_address'
    AND customers_at_locations.updated_at = '2023-12-08 19:29:42.091863'
    AND (customers.characteristics && ARRAY['employed', 'married', 'former_addict']::varchar[])
ORDER BY
    (customers_at_locations.latlong <-> ST_Point(-118.38154, 34.09401)::geography) ASC, customers_at_locations.id ASC
LIMIT 11;
```

If I remove the secondary order by using customers_at_location.id, the index is used as expected. So is it not possible to use the KNN operator with a secondary order by? I've tried this with a multicolumn gist index on latlong and id together and it still doesn't work. Curious if anyone else has worked through a similar use case.

Comment: I suspect you may *actually* be tring to accomplish a different thing than described by your query. Consider your `ORDER BY` here on a higher level: you sort `id`s over `<distance>`, so for each *unique `<distance>` value* you sort the `id`s that have *this same value*. An odd thing to do, really? Can you describe the desired outcome some more? In any way, a sort key that is not part of the *KNN* distance condition cannot be part of the index lookup.

Comment: That's helpful -- thanks! I'm trying to order by both distance and ID to support distance based cursor pagination. I need a unique col (ID in this case) because distance is not unique: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58787039/cursor-based-pagination-for-search-results-without-sequential-unique-ids-eg-lo

Comment: Just wrap your query - without the second sort key - into a CTE and `ORDER BY distance, id` in the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: BTW. this `(customers_at_locations.latlong <-> ST_Point(-118.38154, 34.09401)::geography) / 1609.34) < 50` inside the `WHERE` is not sargable (cannot benefit as an index condition) - this might `customers_at_locations.latlong <-> ST_Point(-118.38154, 34.09401)::geography < (50 * 1609.34)`

Comment: The CTE approach is definitely faster and uses the index. But when using the cursor, I have to add this WHERE clause:
WHERE (distance, id) >= (2.5, 12345)
and for that to work properly, wouldn't I need the dataset sorted by both sort keys? If the dataset isn't in the right order, that where clause wouldn't be effective.

Comment: I know that ST_DWITHIN also utilizes a spatial index, which is something else for me to play around with, but I've found the order by <-> to be much faster than ST_DWITHIN

Answer (score 1):

If you want pagination, use a `CURSOR` - [this is the `SQL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html) variant, there is a [procedural variant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) allowing for more complexity:

```
-- NO SCROLL: do not allow non-sequential cursor access, e.g. FETCH BACKWARD - much faster
-- INSENSITIVE: do not allow for visibility of transactional state changes to the underlying data inside the cursor - much faster
-- WITH HOLD: allow for cross-transaction access to the CURSOR - much easier
DECLARE in_proximity NO SCROLL INSENSITIVE CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT
  t.id,
  t.geog <-> 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOGRAPHY AS dst
FROM
  <table> AS t
WHERE
  ST_DWithin(t.geog, 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOGRAPHY, 1609.34 * 50)
ORDER BY
  2
;

FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM in_proximity;
FETCH 10 FROM in_proximity;
FETCH ALL FROM in_proximity;

-- DO NOT FORGET THIS!!!
CLOSE in_proximity;
```

The initial sort is preserved inside the `CURSOR`, so there is no need to worry about uniqueness etc.

Depending on your application setup and caching, you may want to use a `SCROLL CURSOR` to go backwards.

Problem solved.

---

If you still want to implement pagination through `LIMIT|OFFSET` or sort filters, either run:

```
WITH
  spatial AS (
    SELECT
      t.id,
      t.geog <-> 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOGRAPHY AS dst
    FROM
      <table> AS t
    WHERE
      t.geog <-> 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOGRAPHY <= 50 * 1609.34
    ORDER BY
      t.geog <-> 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOGRAPHY
  ),
  ordering AS (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      spatial
    ORDER BY
      dst, id
  )
-- outer query to allow pagination via filter or LIMIT|OFFSET
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ordering
WHERE
  dst > <DST>
  AND
  id > <ID>
;
```

if you insist on using a *(K)NN* approach - but note that, without a `LIMIT` ***directly affecting*** the *(K)NN* query (in `spatial`), performance will degrade significantly - or, the likely faster, more idiomatic approach:

```
WITH
  spatial AS (
    SELECT
      t.id,
      t.geog <-> 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOGRAPHY AS dst
    FROM
      <table> AS t
    WHERE
      ST_DWithin(t.geog, 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOGRAPHY, 1609.34 * 50)
    ORDER BY
      2, 1
  )
-- outer query to allow pagination via filter or LIMIT|OFFSET
SELECT
  *
FROM
  spatial
WHERE
  dst > <DST>
  AND
  id > <ID>
;
```

Now, given your more complex `JOIN` setup it is possible that the *planner* chooses to use different indexes than the spatial `GIST` when running the `ST_DWithin` approach - while it is quite the in-your-face hint for it to use the spatial `GIST` index in the case of the *(K)NN* approach and its respective `ORDER BY`.

If the *planner* denies the (hopefully actually) faster spatial `GIST` index lookup you will have to isolate the respective table access, rather than using a multi-`JOIN` query.